# Proper way to use HttpClient within Parallel.Foreach to make a large number of POST requests

Tags: .net-core, async-await, dotnet-httpclient, parallel.foreach

As you may see in the code below, on a highlevel this code reads a folder structure recursively and POSTs it's content to an API. Application is .Net core 2.1.

I have this service that makes a POST to an API.

```cs
    public class EnterpriseService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public EnterpriseService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<string> PostTransactionAsync(byte[] payload)
        {
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri("https://www.foo.com/api/transaction")))
            {
                request.Content = new ByteArrayContent(payload);
                HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
        }
    }
```

PostTransactionAsync is being invoked by the caller in the following manner:

```cs
        protected async Task SearchFoldersAsync(List<FileStatusProperties> folders, string root, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return Parallel.ForEach(folders, async entry =>
                {
                    if (entry.Type == FileType.DIRECTORY)
                    {
                        await SearchFoldersAsync(
                            DataLakeStorage.DirectoryGetFiles($"{root}/{entry.PathSuffix}"),
                            $"{root}/{entry.PathSuffix}", cancellationToken);
                        return;
                    }

                    byte[] payload = DataLakeStorage.FileDownload($"{root}/{entry.PathSuffix}");
                    await _enterpriseService.PostTransactionAsync(payload);

                });
            }, cancellationToken);

        }
```

Note that I'm using a HttpClient that is DI'd as a singleton.

I also have a recursive use of Parallel.Foreach.

This code works perfectly for a smaller folder structure with 10K+ files. But when the file number grows (say it reaches about 100K files in the folders) I get a mix of these 2 errors. roughly 20% of the requests succeed. 40% of requests end up in these 2 exceptions each on the _httpClient.SendAsync call. The requests fails after 10 seconds.

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port)
>   is normally permitted

and

> The operation was canceled. Unable to read data from the transport
>   connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a
>   thread exit or an application request. The I/O operation has been
>   aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

I read about the usage of HttpClient and as far as I can tell, I'm not doing anything wrong. But i'm not sure about it's use withing a recursive Parallel.ForEach.

I would like to know what is the recommended way to handle this scenario where I need to make a large number of http requests concurrently?

Comment: In short: you don't. `Parallel.ForEach` is not intended for use with an async delegate. It results in an un-awaitable async void. If you want to spin up multiple async Http calls then `Select` over the incoming collection.

Comment: Can someone pls explain the down vote?

Comment: .NET 6 now has `Parallel.ForEachAsync` which renders essentially every comment and answer - none of which address the question about `HttpClient` - here obsolete. It would be great if someone would answer the actual question as it relates to `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 3):

`Parallel` is for parallelism, which is a form of concurrency that uses multiple threads to split up CPU-bound work across multiple cores. What you want is *asynchronous* concurrency, which is a more appropriate approach for doing multiple I/O-bound operations concurrently.

Asynchronous concurrency is most easily done by starting a `Task` for each item (usually using `Select`), and then doing `await Task.WhenAll` over all those tasks. Something like this:

```
protected async Task SearchFoldersAsync(List<FileStatusProperties> folders, string root, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
  var tasks = folders.Select(async entry =>
  {
    if (entry.Type == FileType.DIRECTORY)
    {
      await SearchFoldersAsync(
          DataLakeStorage.DirectoryGetFiles($"{root}/{entry.PathSuffix}"),
          $"{root}/{entry.PathSuffix}", cancellationToken);
      return;
    }

    byte[] payload = DataLakeStorage.FileDownload($"{root}/{entry.PathSuffix}");
    await _enterpriseService.PostTransactionAsync(payload);
  }).ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Comment: 'which is a more appropriate approach for doing multiple I/O-bound operations concurrently.' - can you please elaborate a bit more on this please? I tried out this appraoch and the performance dropped significantly. so i would really like to understand if there's any situation where parallel foreach should not be used. thanks.

Comment: `async` does I/O by using a callback model: code is notified when the I/O completes. `Parallel` uses a blocking model: the calling thread is blocked until the operation completes. So `Parallel` uses more threads and memory to do the same thing.

Comment: I think this answer would be better adding a SemaphoreSlim to avoid creating infinte tasks and handling your max concurrent calls.

Comment: Now that .NET6 supports `Parallel.ForEachAsync` it would be nice to know if that would be a viable approach to the original problem presented using `HttpClient`.

Comment: @EmperorEto: Sure, it can be used for that. `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is intended more for mixed CPU-and-I/O workloads, but it would work for mainly-I/O workloads as well.

Comment: @StephenCleary thanks. I started a new question to dive a little deeper on this, if you're interested in weighing in further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77801101/httpclient-and-parallel-foreachasync-for-large-number-of-file-transfers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to address the Parallel vs async...

But this specific error

> Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

Would seem to be due to the fact that you can only have about 65k connections to from 1 system to a single port on another system.

Assuming the existing server process is using port 80, you could start up additional processes that use other ports.  But you'd need more than 1 HttpClient and would need to round robin or something between them.  Too many processes and you're likely to start hitting limits of open file descriptors on either the client or the server.