# HttpClient and Parallel.ForEachAsync for large number of file transfers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, concurrency, dotnet-httpclient, parallel.foreachasync

I have a need for one ASP.NET Core server to download via the backend a massive number of files from another server using GET requests. (The platform doesn't matter, assume Dropbox, OneDrive, or anything else with API access).

Doing this serially is much too slow, so I have used `Parallel.ForEachAsync` to iterate through the list of file IDs to be retrieved and GET them in parallel using a single `HttpClient` instance. The approach works so far in a development environment, but I have some concerns about whether this method is appropriate for production.

Here's the question: *What potential pitfals could arise from this method and what should be done to mitigate them (or what approach should be used instead, if this method is fatally flawed)?*

To elaborate further, here are some of my concerns -

- Do I need to limit the amount of parallelism using `ParallelOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism` and if so what should that value be? I realize HTTP standards suggest no more than 2 concurrent connections to the same host, however modern browsers appear to use 6 or more sometimes. Obviously imposing no limit results in the fastest transfers, but is this safe to do?
- Do I run a risk of running out of outbound TCP/IP ports to the remote host if too many users are doing the same thing at the same time? Will `HttpClient` wait for ports to free up or just fail? Do I need to handle such failures with a retry?
- Do I run a risk of impacting the remote server negatively if I don't limit the concurrent requests? Could my application be mistaken for a DDOS attack? Would this risk be mitigated if I limit to 6 like a browser does?
- Should I expect (and handle) potential HTTP 429 responses?
- Other risks I haven't thought of?

PS - I realize this question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56657923/proper-way-to-use-httpclient-within-parallel-foreach-to-make-a-large-number-of-p), but unfortunately that question predated .NET6 and `Parallel.ForEachAsync` so the answers largely focused on the pitfalls of using the blocking `Parallel.ForEach` rather than the networking issues.

Comment: Most of the above cannot be answered in a general manner. Set up a production-equivalent test environment and run your horses. See what happens. Take measurements. Plan improvements based on the results. If you hit services not owned by yourself, check agreed-upon numbers in contracts / small print. Keep well below those.

Comment: _"Should I expect (and handle) potential HTTP 429 responses?"_ - It's over the internet. You should _expect_ **all** sorts of errors. Maybe even ... _the spanish inquisition_ !

Comment: You can try AbotX which has a parallel crawler framework that supports this  https://github.com/sjdirect/abotx#parallel-crawler-engine

Comment: maybe zip the files first to reduce file size and count?

Comment: @Fildor obviously. urlreader: not an option. I don't have control of the remote content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to limit the amount of parallelism

Yes.

> what should that value be?

Difficult to tell, and will likely depend on the backend. 2-6 might be a good place to start, and adjust up or down as required.

> Do I run a risk of running out of outbound TCP/IP ports to the remote host if too many users are doing the same thing at the same time?

According to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/517175/what-happens-if-the-server-runs-out-of-ports), the server should never run out of ports if http is used. The client (i.e. your server) could run out of ports, but you will likely run out of other resources (bandwith, threads, memory etc) before running out of ports.

> Do I need to handle such failures with a retry?

you will need error handling.  Retrying a few times before escalating the error is a very typical solution.

> Do I run a risk of impacting the remote server negatively if I don't limit the concurrent requests? Could my application be mistaken for a DDOS attack? Would this risk be mitigated if I limit to 6 like a browser does?

Yes and yes. The risk will be lower with fewer requests, but would not be eliminated even if you are only doing sequential requests. It will depend on the specific service. The more you pay for the service, the higher the limits will likely be. Limits will likely not be documented, so it might be advisable to start slow.

> Should I expect (and handle) potential HTTP 429 responses?

It depends on your goals. You could perhaps make some dynamic system that reduces request frequency depending on the response from the server. Or you could just find a static limit that works well enough.

> download via the backend a massive number of files from another server using GET requests. (The platform doesn't matter, assume Dropbox, OneDrive, or anything else with API access)

Keep in mind that the terms of service might be incompatible with whatever you are trying to do. And the service provider may reserve the right to terminate service at their discretion.

Overall you will likely have less issues if you use fewer larger files than many small files.

Comment: Thanks. So from the perspective of my own server's health, it doesn't sound like there's any need to limit the parallelism (no chance of running out of ports/sockets/threads/etc). The need to limit it would arise entirely from how the remote server will react/behave, and I'll need to adapt depending on what that response/behavior is. Is that a fair summary?

Comment: The client could run out of ports though. I admit you'd need truly massive parallelism to hit that, especially if using HTTP2. A 429 response on many server has a header inidicating how long to wait, it's worth checking for it.

Comment: @Charlieface sorry who is the "client" you're referencing? My server is talking to the remote server, so my server is technically the "client" here. So my server CAN run out of outbound ports, or can it not? This is a pretty important question.

Comment: @EmperorEto Yes that's correct, your server is the client. But HTTP2 can multiplex, and you also have many (tens of?) thousands of ephemeral ports also, which can be used concurrently. Either server would almost certainly run out of bandwidth first.

Comment: @Charlieface yeah ok that's what I thought thank you. So this answer is a little off the mark in saying "the server should never run out of ports if http is used." That would be true of the remote server but not my server acting in a client capacity. That said, I guess the number of available CPU threads would also be a limiting factor long before ports run out, no?

Comment: @EmperorEto a file transfer is unlikely to consume many CPU resources, so most likely you'll run out of network bandwidth while the CPU will be sitting almost idle. At least that's what I would expect to happen.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias what I'm getting at is whether `Parallel.ForEachAsync` will run into other constraints such as CPU/thread count before outbound ports were to run out. Ultimately the question is whether running out of ports is actually a concern or not. My difficulty with the above answer is that I think he's brushing aside the port issue a bit too quickly.

Comment: I am not familiar with outbound ports as finite resources, but I am familiar with CPU and threads. I would be highly surprised if the CPU is maxed out before the network bandwidth, considering that downloading a file doesn't require much work from the CPU. Basically the network card is writing directly to memory. As for threads, I am not expecting high utilization either, because pure asynchronous operations require [no threads](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). About outbound ports I have nothing to say.

Comment: @EmperorEto far enough, added a note about ports on the client.

Comment: @JonasH good deal thanks. I'll go ahead and accept the answer but I do note that there's still a potential disagreement here between your opining that you'd run out of CPU resources first and Theodor thinking you'd run out of "bandwidth" first (though I think he really means client ports). Either way keeping the parallelism in the single digits definitely seems prudent.

Comment: @EmperorEto I don't see the disagreement. I have no idea what resource will run out first, and it will likely depend on the application anyway. I would think ports is only a problem in super high scaling scenarios, or pathological cases, i.e. huge number of connections without any traffic.